# foreach loop string to multiply digits together

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I am trying to take a number and multiply each digit together. eg: 1234 -> 1x2x3x4 = 24. here is what I have so far. (JAVA)

```
int sum = 1;
int num = 1234;
String str = Integer.toString(num);
for(String i: str) {
    sum *=Integer.parseInt(i);
}
```

I am not sure how to use the foreach loop with string arrays.

I understand that a string is just an array of chars so why shouldnt this work?

Comment: Is this java? may be worth adding appropriate language tag (there's a special field for tags)

Comment: @jhnc yes. this is java. OP updated

Comment: There’s no need to covert to string. Hint: `1234 % 10 = 4` and `1234 / 10 = 123`

Comment: My eclipse compiler says: `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` (Error)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i will eventually get to much bigger numbers so i need a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the String to char array and then loop over the char array.

```
for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
     sum *= Character.getNumericValue(ch);
}
```

or

```
for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
     sum *= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf("" + ch));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way of doing it instead of generating a string and iterating it would be taking the last digit and dividing the number by 10 until there are digits left. Sample code:

```
int product = 1;
int num = 1234;
while(num > 0)
{
    product *= num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i thought of this, but i eventually get to bigger numbers (num will change). so i cannot do it this way.

Comment: @SakshamGoyal In order to do that, you can't use the num variable. You should get the "1234" directly into string.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 it is just one statement.

```
int value = Integer.toString(1234).chars()
            .map(c -> Character.getNumericValue(c))             
            .reduce((a, b) -> a * b).getAsInt();
```

Comment: this is really complicated and i dont understand this code (i am a noob). thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As no one else mentioned, you can also do it using stream-API introduced in Java-8.

```java
public static long findProductOfDigits(String n) {
    return n.chars()
            .map(c -> Character.getNumericValue(c))
            .mapToLong(i -> i)
            .reduce(1l, (a, b) -> a * b);
}
```

As your input number can grow beyond `long` (64 bits), so your result can also go beyond `int`. So we can use `long` for the result, instead of `int`. Though this is not the best solution as `long` result can still overflow. In that case you can consider returning `BigInteger`.

But I think the main idea is to give this other possibility of using streams.

Comment: this is really complicated and i dont understand this code (i am a noob). thank you for your answer

Comment: I understand that this code appears to be complicated to you as you are a noob, and if you come from a C or C++ background, then it might make no sense, but IMO this is a more expressive way to write code in Java. And if you are learning Java, it won't hurt to learn the Streams-API. (And believe me, it's worth learning it.)